# Problem mounting ntfs partition to /media

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, ntfs

I'm fairly new to linux and I've been trying to synchronise my music on my dual boot system (windows 8 and ubuntu 14.04).

I have tried manually editing fstab and using the disks program, but no matter what tutorial I follow I get an error on startup saying that an error occured while mounting to /media/storage (I made the storage folder and I want to mount to media so that the drive shows up in the places menu).

here is the blkid (the drive I'm attempting to mount is labeled gen-storage):

```
~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="WINRE_DRV" UUID="8A043EA6043E9563" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SYSTEM_DRV" UUID="EE41-0723" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="LRS_ESP" UUID="8241-4B8C" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Windows8_OS" UUID="983444A634448968" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="gen-storage" UUID="EE24706024702DA9" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="84e87c04-5a35-453c-82fe-435ee00ff863" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="22c03c2e-cb96-44fd-b26e-254bc8d7887e" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda9: UUID="80f099b5-7cb5-4f7a-8ed7-714c6dde26bc" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda10: UUID="941E2E671E2E429A" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda11: LABEL="LENOVO" UUID="CA984AD5984ABFA5" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda12: LABEL="PBR_DRV" UUID="9AFA46DDFA46B573" TYPE="ntfs"
```

here is an example of one way I have tried to change the fstab file (from a tutorial):

# storage mount

```
UUID=EE24706024702DA9 /media/storage/ ntfs-3g auto,user,rw 0 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fstab entry looks fine. But since you have entry in the fstab, `root` will try to mount the partition while booting. So root user should have permission in the folder `/media/storage`

So change the ownership of the folder by giving the following command

`sudo chown root:root /media/storage`

and then give the permission to every user who want to access it

`sudo chmod -R 777 /media/storage`

reboot and it should mount properly. After it's mounted , create a symlink using the following command and you should see a media folder(shortcut?) in your home

`ln -s /media/storage /home/<username>`